# jquery.mb.YTPlayer - disable controls

Tags: jquery

I use this plugin to play video on website jquery.mb.YTPlayer. But when the video is loading it shows video controls "Play", "pause"..., I need to disable it. As soon as the video starts to play they dissapear.

```
<video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" volume="5" autobuffer="" controls="">
   <source src="" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="" type="video/webm">
   <source src="" type="video/ogg ogv"> 
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this issue, if you are using pupunzi mb.YTPlayer you then need to put a `data-property` into your html.

It should look something like this:

```
<div id="[ID Your Video]" class="player" dataProperties="{videoURL:'BsekcY04xvQ',showControls: false}"></div>
```